# Prove that the product of four distinct primes (bigger than 10) which differ only in their last digits (if it exists) always ends in $189$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was reading about [numbers](http://www.numbergossip.com), when I came across this amazing fact/unique property of the number $189$ :

The product of four distinct primes (bigger than $10$) which differ only in their last digits (if it exists) always ends in $189$.

Is there a good way to prove this ? There are infinitely many examples which satisfy this, since there are infinitely many primes. Also, why does it not work for primes below $10$? I am not very familiar with number-theory, so I can not do much "modulos" and other "commonly-used" methods in number theory. So, I can not post any of my own "research/effort/work" on the problem. What I have done is just tested the fact on various primes $\Big($:-($\Big)$.

Thanks in Advance ! :-)

Comment: $(10 k + 1)(10 k + 3)(10k + 7)(10k + 9) = 10000 k^4 + 20000 k^3 + 13000 k^2 + 3000 k + 189$.

Comment: It's not clear at all that there are infinitely many quadruples of primes with this property. This would imply the twin prime conjecture.

Comment: @user49640 OH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! That was so simple !!! Thanks a lot !! :-)

Comment: One can prove a "stronger theorem": A *prime quadruple* is a sequence of four consecutive primes $p$, $p+2$, $p+6$, $p+8$. For any such quadruple  the decimal representation of the product of its members ends in 189.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work for primes below $10$ because

$$2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$$

does not end in $189$.

---

However, if the primes are bigger than $10$, then their final digit can only ever be $1,3,7$ or $9$. Given that the four primes only differ in the last digit, and the last digit is one of four possible digits, you also know that **all** of these digits will be taken. In other words, the primes will be equal to

$$10k + 1\\10k+3\\10k+7\\10k+9$$

Now, have a look at the product of these four numbers.

Comment: Sorry I deleted the question. I actually did not know that you have posted an answer. I thought that the question is a very stupid one, so I thought of deleting it. Anyways thanks for the answer :-).

Comment: @Nirbhay The question is pretty far from stupid if you ask me.

Comment: For me it will be stupid question LOL. XD . Can you please help me out with [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2159042/evaluating-the-integral-frac122n-2-int-01-fracx4n-left1-x-right?noredirect=1#comment4440868_2159042) ????? I'll be grateful to you....

Answer (score 1):

Four primes greater than $10$ that differ only in their last digit will need to have the corresponding number that ends in $5$ be divisible by $3$, so will be of the form $30m+k$, with $k$ values of $\{11,13,17,19\}$.

The last $3$ digits of their product $(30m+11)(30m+13)(30m+17)(30m+19)$ will be the same as the last $3$ digits of:

$\begin{align}& A+B+C \\
\text{where } &A:=900m^2(11\cdot13+11\cdot17+11\cdot19+13\cdot17+13\cdot 19+17\cdot19) \\
&B:= 30m(11\cdot13\cdot17+11\cdot13\cdot19+11\cdot17\cdot19+13\cdot17\cdot 19)\\
& C:=11\cdot 13\cdot17\cdot 19
\end{align}$

...because as soon as we have a factor of $1000$ in a term, it no longer affects the last three digits. Also because of this, we can simplify the first term above:

$\begin{align}  A' &:= 900m^2(1\cdot3+1\cdot7+1\cdot9+3\cdot7+3\cdot 9+7\cdot9)\\
&= 900m^2(3+7+9+21+27+63) \\
&= 900m^2(120)
\end{align}$

Now we see that this first terms is divisible by $1000$ so is no longer interesting, so we can ignore it and proceed with $B$, the $30m$ term:

$\begin{align}  B &= 30m(11\cdot13\cdot17+11\cdot13\cdot19+11\cdot17\cdot19+13\cdot17\cdot 19)\\
&= 30m(30\cdot13\cdot17+30\cdot11\cdot19) \\
&= 900m(221+209) \\
&= 900m(430) \\
\end{align}$

So $B$ is also divisible by $1000$ and the last $3$ digits will just match those of $C$, which doesn't depend on $m$.

$\begin{align}  C &=  11\cdot13\cdot17\cdot 19)\\
&= 221 \cdot 209 \\
&= 46189 \\
\end{align}$

giving the last three digits as $189$ as claimed.